# Bada 1.2 and Flash. How shall I understand such thing?

Tags: html, flash, apache-flex, browser, bada

So I got Bada Wave II.. It [shall have FP9](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bada_%28operating_system%29#Architecture) and Adobe site thinks it has! [image: 9.1.122] but we see strange banner on top. So I thought - grate - we have it... And I [built this fith flex builder 3 for FP 9.0.124](http://superior0.narod.ru/fp9/PlayerOne.html) but when I go to it I see nothing but this [image: landscape]

or [image: portret]...

Code behind is simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
    <mx:VideoDisplay id="va" source="http://imgproc.apmath.spbu.ru:4773/robot669394444.flv?action=read" autoPlay="true"  metadataReceived="doHust()" left="10" right="10" top="10" bottom="38"/>
    <mx:TextArea bottom="10"  text="" height="20" right="10" left="10" id="ta"/>
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
    public function doHust():void
        {
        ta.text = va.totalTime.toString() + " " + va.source.toString() + " " + va.playheadTime.toString() + " Build By Cloud Forever team in 2011 for testing Bada 1.2 (Samsung Wave II) flash capabileties in browser. Build for FP 9.0.124";  
        } 
            ]]>
    </mx:Script>
</mx:Application>
```

I also tried to compile it for FP 9.0.28 which was one of big FP game changers... but no luck.. So I [whent to Google](http://www.google.ru/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=flash%20player%209%20demo&qscrl=1) and [found something that worked on Bada and at the same time was FP9!) It was not working 100% correctly as you can see but any way - I can operate with out navigation](http://wwis-dubc1-vip118.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/productinfo/features/experience/)... Here are screenshots:[image: main site intro] [image: proof link] [image: rendering performance demo] [image: video alpha channel... with no video (but frame is transparent)] [image: some text rendering stuff] [image: BTW here frame rate was smooth] [image: AS3 runs...] [image: Runs at 2 FPS...] [image: Video buffering] [image: Video not playing in landscape] [image: nor in portret]. Note that flash content was unscrollable, unzoomable and browser about was showing [image: Samsung Dol (delphin picture here) in Browser v2.2 (open source WebKit based software)]...

So at leasted it worked! So I descided to try and go into html... [and modified my flex builder generated html into something as close as possible to that sample that worked](http://superior0.narod.ru/fp9/) and it shows this same wary FP9 logo thing...:[image: modified html, still no flash]... so It seems that I can not run Flex, mxml based projects on my bada... or can I? any tips?

So what does this red/white FP9 square icon thing mean?

***Update:***

So.. ok - no FB.. but we still have normal FP9 and Flash CS5... so we can build such video playing code in Flash Pro and try to look at it...

So my code:

```
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.NetStatusEvent;
    import flash.events.SecurityErrorEvent;
    import flash.media.Video;
    import flash.net.NetConnection;
    import flash.net.NetStream;
    import flash.events.Event;

    var videoURL:String = "http://imgproc.apmath.spbu.ru:4773/robot669394444.flv?action=read";
    var connection:NetConnection;
    var stream:NetStream;
    var video:Video = new Video();        

    function main() {
        connection = new NetConnection();
        connection.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusHandler);
        connection.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityErrorHandler);
        connection.connect(null);
    }

    function netStatusHandler(event:NetStatusEvent):void {
        switch (event.info.code) {
            case "NetConnection.Connect.Success":
                connectStream();
                break;
            case "NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound":
                trace("Stream not found: " + videoURL);
                break;
        }
    }

    function securityErrorHandler(event:SecurityErrorEvent):void {
        trace("securityErrorHandler: " + event);
    }

    function connectStream():void {
        var stream:NetStream = new NetStream(connection);
        stream.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusHandler);
        stream.client = {};
        stream.client.onMetaData = l_onMetaData;
        stream.client.onCuePoint = l_onCuePoint;
        video.attachNetStream(stream);
        stream.play(videoURL);
        addChild(video);
    }

    function l_onMetaData(info:Object):void {
        trace("metadata: duration=" + info.duration + " width=" + info.width + " height=" + info.height + " framerate=" + info.framerate);
        video.width = info.width;
        video.height = info.height;
    }

    function l_onCuePoint(info:Object):void {
        trace("cuepoint: time=" + info.time + " name=" + info.name + " type=" + info.type);
    }

main();
```

And my app online here for [FP9.0.0](http://superior0.narod.ru/fp9/flash_Pro.html) and we get same bad results =-(

So.. ok - I get it no FP9.. so let us [try Flash lite 2 (flash 7 analog)](http://superior0.narod.ru/fp9/mobile.html)  [fla file here](http://superior0.narod.ru/fp9/mobile.fla) and 2 code lines in it:

```
WideoWid.contentPath = "http://imgproc.apmath.spbu.ru:4773/robot669394444.flv?action=read";
WideoWid.play();
```

(BTW nokia N5800 played that=)

[image: and we see again bad thing...]

Comment: Why do you want to run Flex on bada?  It'll be slow as hell and useless since it wasn't even made for mobile back then.  I dunno, seems kind of irrelevant.

Comment: @J_A_X: my main objective is to play FLV video flex, flash does not matter.

Comment: Yeah, definitely use flash, not flex.  It should work fairly easily, but I have no experience with Bada, so you're on your own.

Answer (score 1):

Had you set `Project Properties > Flex Compiler > Adobe Flash Player Options > Use a specific version` to 9.0.0?

Comment: I used 9.0.124 and 9.0.28... and I'we got same result on bouth... and any way adobes site talls us about 9.1.122